# issue in reading files in R where file names are in lower cases , upper cases or other cases

Tags: r

I have multiple file whose names are not in proper format. For example, one file might have name like "TEST_1.XLSX", the other has name like "test_2.xlsx" and, for worse, another file has name as "tEsT_3.XlsX".

When I tried to read file using:

```
df <- xlsx::read.xlsx(file.choose(), sheetIndex = 1)
```

it reads the file with names and extension in "lower cases" but failed to read all others.

Can there be a way to avoid such issues and read all the files despite whatever the case of names/extension is?

Answer (score 2):

import all files in your folder and store the file names in a vector:

```
file_names <- list.files(path = "path/where/files/are")
```

then import each file and store it in a list

```
df_list<-list()
for(i in 1:length(file_names){
    df_list[[i]] <- xlsx::read.xlsx(as.character(file_names[i]))
}
```

To avoid further issues like that you can use to_lower() when saving the files again.

Comment: I think I need to use `to_lower()` before reading the files and not  for saving the files in lower cases. Thanks for your help.